# How to extract substring from pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to retrieve only the first part of the string for the entire column.

```
meta["Cell_type"].str.rstrip(" ")[0]
```

Data:

`meta.iloc[1:5]`

```
pd.DataFrame({'Assay Type': {'SRR9200814': 'RNA-Seq',
  'SRR9200815': 'RNA-Seq',
  'SRR9200816': 'RNA-Seq',
  'SRR9200817': 'RNA-Seq'},
 'Cell_type': {'SRR9200814': 'normal neural stem cells',
  'SRR9200815': 'normal neural stem cells',
  'SRR9200816': 'normal neural stem cells',
  'SRR9200817': 'normal neural stem cells'},
 'Type': {'SRR9200814': 'diploid',
  'SRR9200815': 'diploid',
  'SRR9200816': 'diploid',
  'SRR9200817': 'diploid'}})
```

Current output:

```
'normal neural stem cells'
```

Desired output:

```
Run
SRR9200813          normal
SRR9200814          glioblastoma 
SRR9200815          normal 
SRR9200816          normal
SRR9200817          normal
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use str.split:

```
meta['Cell_type'] = meta['Cell_type'].str.split(' ').str[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way that `apply` the function `x.split()`, that splits the string in token, to the entire column and takes the first element in the list.

```py
df["Cell_type"].apply(lambda x : x.split()[0])

# SRR9200814    normal
# SRR9200815    normal
# SRR9200816    normal
# SRR9200817    normal
```

You can assign the result to the column if you want to modify your dataframe.

```py
df["Cell_type"] =  df["Cell_type"].apply(lambda x : x.split()[0])

#            Assay Type Cell_type     Type
# SRR9200814    RNA-Seq    normal  diploid
# SRR9200815    RNA-Seq    normal  diploid
# SRR9200816    RNA-Seq    normal  diploid
# SRR9200817    RNA-Seq    normal  diploid
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I want to return it as a string

Answer (score 0):

```
meta["Cell_type"].str.split(n = 1, expand = True)[0]


SRR9200814    normal
SRR9200815    normal
SRR9200816    normal
SRR9200817    normal
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

ref : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I want to return it as a string

Comment: there is no string dtype it is same as object

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) instead of [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
>>> meta['Cell_type'].str.extract('(\S+)', expand=False)
SRR9200814    normal
SRR9200815    normal
SRR9200816    normal
SRR9200817    normal
Name: Cell_type, dtype: object
```

**Note**: `\S` matches any non-whitespace character.

You can also do:

```
meta['Result'] = meta['Cell_type'].str.extract('(\S+)')
print(meta)

# Output
           Assay Type                 Cell_type     Type  Result
SRR9200814    RNA-Seq  normal neural stem cells  diploid  normal
SRR9200815    RNA-Seq  normal neural stem cells  diploid  normal
SRR9200816    RNA-Seq  normal neural stem cells  diploid  normal
SRR9200817    RNA-Seq  normal neural stem cells  diploid  normal
```